# Adjusting the left margin of List of tables and List of figures in latex

Tags: table-of-contents

I am in the process of editing my final PhD. thesis using latex.
I need to satisfy certain formatting criteria before I can submit my final thesis to graduate school.

One problem I am facing right now is how to change the left margin of `LIST OF TABLES` and `LIST OF FIGURES` to 1.25 inches (see the attached figure below).
[image]

Currently, the left margins of all other sections are 1.25 inches and I would like to know to how to change the left margin of `LIST OF TABLES` and `LIST OF FIGURES` without affecting other sections.

I guess it has something to do with the following code, but I am not sure which line I need to change exactly

```
%% tocloft typesets ToC title, so we must give it our heading formats
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\ncsu@headingformat}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 00.00}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\newcommand{\thesislistoffigures}{%
\singlespacing%
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
\setlength{\ncsu@leading}{\baselineskip-\ncsu@capitalheight}%
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}%
{\ncsu@afterschapsep-\cftbeforechapskip-\ncsu@leading}%
\listoffigures%
\clearpage%
\ncsu@defaultspacing%
}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\ncsu@headingformat}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
```

I found two posts related to my problem but could not resolve my issue completely.

[List of tables and List of figures right margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122308/list-of-tables-and-list-of-figures-right-margin)

[List of Figures page Margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141558/list-of-figures-page-margins)

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could shed some lights on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) *always*.

Answer (score 3):

The space on the left is called `indent` you can change it with `cfttabindent{<value>}`  for tables and `\cftfigindent{<value>}` for figures like

```
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{1.25in}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{1.25in}
```

Here are the default values (screen shot from `tocloft` manual)

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe} %% for demo only
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{1.25in}    %% adjust as you like
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{1.25in}    %% adjust as you like
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{some chapter}
\section{some section}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \caption{some table}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

For margins are violated bit, you have to provide the text. However, you may try adding `\usepackage{microtype}` to your preamble. In most of the cases this works well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the problem with the margin violated by "graphene/substrate":

In general, `\sloppy` can help to alleviate linebreak problems in narrow tables. Here, however, it wouldn't. The linebreak algorithm fails when words are connected by a slash. You need to set breakpoints manually. `graphene/sub\-strate` should do.