# Add en dash after numbering in list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I want to change the layout of the list of algorithms provided by algorithm2e from this

`1 Sorting...........................15`

to this

`Algorithm 1 -- Sorting..............15`

I was already able to add the "Algorithm" word by following the instructions in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96972/30998), but could not get the en dash to appear. I tried to renew the `\numberline` to add the en dash, but the results weren't satisfactory.
I know the `memoir` class has the `\cftfigureaftersnum` for inserting text after the figure numbers in the LOF and the `\cfttableaftersnum` as the equivalent for tables, but I could not find an equivalent for algorithms.

Any thoughts on this?

**EDIT:** I am giving support to the LaTeX class from my university, which is based on memoir. It uses algorithm2e as the default package for creating algorithms and does not use tocloft.

Comment: Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you use? (It would seem to be `memoir`, but it's not entirely clear.) Also, please state (a) which package(s) you use to create algorithm-type environments and (b) how the List of Algorithms is produced. Having this information would let potential answer-writers eliminate a lot of inefficient and pointless guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *native* way of setting the LoA entries within [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (or default classes loading [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)) is to make each entry mimic the style of the LoF. This is easily achieved by adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@algocf\l@figure
\makeatother
```

to the document preamble. Now the regular `\cftX...` macros can by used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\let\l@algocf\l@figure% Handle LoA exactly like LoF
\makeatother

\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{{%
  % Locally update LoA entries as they are now similar to LoF
  \renewcommand{\cftfigurepresnum}[1]{\gdef\algonum{##1}}% Grab algorithm number
  \renewcommand{\cftfigureaftersnumb}{Algorithm~\algonum~--~}%
  \setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{0pt}%
  \oldlistofalgorithms
}}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, both of your answers worked like a charm! Since I already had some custom formatting in my list of figures, this answer worked better, but I tried both and they both worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (or the default document classes, even under the addition of [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)). However, you can modify the LoA entry setter - `\l@algocf` - quite readily:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\let\oldnumberline\numberline% Store \numberline
\newcommand{\algnumberline}[1]{Algorithm~#1 -- }
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \let\numberline\algnumberline% Update \numberline
  \oldlistofalgorithms
  \let\numberline\oldnumberline% Restore \numberline
}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to [remove the indent of the LoA entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334056/5764), also add the following:

```
\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334060/5764
\renewcommand{\l@algocf}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}% Remove indent of algorithm in LoA
\makeatother
```

[image]