# Adjust left margin of list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

How can I adjust the left margin of the list of algorithms?

**What I have tried**

For the list of figures and tables, the left margin could be adjusted like explained in [Adjusting left margin of LOT and LOF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334056/adjusting-left-margin-of-lot-and-lof) :

```
\renewcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
```

However, this does not work:

```
\renewcommand\l@algorithm{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
```

The margin is not affected and I get the following warning:

```
Command \l@algorithm undefined. \renewcommand\l@algorithm
```

I have tried several variations: `l@algorithms`, `l@algo`, but none works. I was able to find the definition of `l@figure` in `book.cls`, but I could not find anything related to list of algorithms.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From how the `\listofalgorithms` and `\listof` are defined,

```tex
$ latexdef -p algorithm -s listofalgorithms
% algorithm.sty, line 97:
\newcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listof{algorithm}{\listalgorithmname}}

$ latexdef -p float -s \listof
% float.sty, line 127:
\newcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
    \float@listhead{#2}%
    \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
      \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}}
```

we can see `\l@algorithm` is not defined until `\listof{algorithm}{...}` is used. This explains the error `Command \l@algorithm undefined.`, and will also overwrite existing definition of `\l@algorithm`.

In example below the problem is solved by redefining `\l@algorithm` at the beginning of aux file `\jobname.loa`, which is input by `\@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}` in `\listof`.

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}

\addtocontents{loa}{%
  \protect\renewcommand\protect\l@algorithm{\protect\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}%
  \protected@file@percent%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

[image: outpuf of \listoffigures]
[image: output of \listofalgorithms]

Answer (score 5):

The KOMA-Script classes load and use package `tocbasic`. Therefore you do not have to redefine internal commands.

The indent of figure and table entries can be changed by

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure,table}
```

If you want to clone the figure settings for the algorithm entries, you can use:

```latex
%get list of algorithms under control of tocbasic:
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listoftoc[\listalgorithmname]{loa}}
% algorithm entries should use same settings as figure entries
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=figure,
  indent:=figure,
  numwidth:=figure
]{tocline}{algorithm}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{algorithm}
% adjust the indent of figure and table entries
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure,table}

%get list of algorithms under control of tocbasic:
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listoftoc[\listalgorithmname]{loa}}
% algorithm entries should use same settings as figure entries
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=figure,
  indent:=figure,
  numwidth:=figure
]{tocline}{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\end{document}
```